# Is there a body that assists in requesting source code from companies thay are required by license to release their codeass

Tags: software, open-source-software

In short, I want to have the source code of the kernel of a specific Android phone that is produced by a one specific reputable south Korean company.

They are using Android, thus they are obligated by AOSP's license to release any code they modified for the phone.

However, they sometimes don't release the code, sometimes release it in a significant delay.

Additionally, sometimes they release code that I suspect doesn't match the actual software installed on the device (by inspecting the released code and comparing it with the binary on the device or the functionality of the device)

My question is what is my best course of action in this case to receive the correct up to date code. I already tried contacting them multiple times.

Comment: I don't think this is a Law question. However, you might be interested in the [Software Freedom Conservancy](https://sfconservancy.org/copyleft-compliance/), which has experience with such situations.

Comment: Funny typo in title?

Comment: @paulgarrett no “codeass” is a technical term referring to the exit function most commonly located at the end or back of the code. This comment also has a technical name: “joke”.

Comment: @DaleM, wow, I never had heard this! Thanks! :)